# How to get "AnimationDrawable" event

Tags: android, animation, drawable

I am working on game application and i use **AnimationDrawable** for image change.
    but problem is i want imageview invisible when Animation is finish.so what should i do
    for this.

```
My code is like this...

 mAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
         mAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d5),50);
         mAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d4),50);
         mAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d3),50);
         mAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d2),50);
         mAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d1),150);
         mAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d2),50);
         mAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d3),50);
         mAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d4),50);
         mAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d5),50);
       mAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_transparent),50);


         mAnimation.setOneShot(true);
         mDogImage.setImageDrawable(mAnimation);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event or listener that will notify you.You just need to apply the trick

Use `mAnimation.getNumberOfFrames();` to get total number of frames and since each frame will last long for 50ms.So your animation is supposed to end in `mAnimation.getNumberOfFrames() * 50` ms.

For  eg  if you have 9 frames and each frame has duration of 50ms then your animation is going to end in 450ms.

So conclusion will be you will make your `ImageView` invisible after 450ms once animation starts.